# How to remove the "Add World Clock" in the notification area?

Tags: gnome, notification, time, gnome-clocks

I'm on Ubuntu 20.10 and in this update, the events show at the bottom of the calendar along with the add world clock option as in the screenshot below.

[image]

I know this got here because of I installed "gnome-clocks" but I use clocks option quite often but not the world clock. So, I would like to remove the option to add world clock without removing the `gnome-clocks` package.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to install the [Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) extension and use this setting:

Supported in Gnome versions [3.36 up to 45](https://gitlab.gnome.org/jrahmatzadeh/just-perfection)[image]

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by creating, installing and enabling the `gnome-shell extension`.

[image]

```
1. mkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/remove_world_clocks_button@name.mail.com
2. cd $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/remove_world_clocks_button@name.mail.com
3. nano extension.js
```

paste below content in the `extension.js` file

```
'use strict';

const Main = imports.ui.main;
const DateMenu = Main.panel.statusArea.dateMenu

class RemoveWorldClocks {
    constructor() {
    }

    enable() {
    DateMenu._clocksItem.hide();
    }

    disable() {
    DateMenu._clocksItem.show();
    }
}

function init() {
    return new RemoveWorldClocks();
}
```

Save the file.

```
4. nano metadata.json
```

paste the below content in `metadata.json` file

```
{
  "name": "Remove World Clocks Button",
  "description": "Remove World Clocks Button from dateMenu",
  "uuid": "remove_world_clocks_button@name.mail.com",
  "shell-version": [
    "3.36",
    "3.38",
    "40"
  ]
}
```

Save the file.

restart the gnome-shell with Alt+F2 r Enter Method. If its wayland server you need to logout and logback in.

enable the extension with below command.

```
5. gnome-extensions enable remove_world_clocks_button@name.mail.com
```

[image]

Comment: Works as expected! Thanks!

Comment: Great answer! For anyone unfamiliar with extension config, it is worth noting that `metadata.json` lists the compatible versions. So, if you receive warning that the extension is incompatible, add your Gnome version to the list, like: `, "41"`